# Check that Serilog is configured correctly

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, serilog

In my ASP.NET Core Web API application I have a Serilog set up to log different types of events (Information, Warning etc) into different tables in a SQL Server database with subloggers and also all events goes into one File.

File logging works fine, but SQL Server logging is not. Dedicated tables in database are being created automatically, but nothing is being written into them. I use the `sa` login while connecting to database, so it is not about roles and permissions.

My current configuration is as follows:

```
"WriteTo": [
  {
    "Name": "Debug",
    "Args": {
      "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss}] [{Level:u3}] {Message:l} {NewLine}"
    }
  },
  {
    "Name": "File",
    "Args": {
      "Path": "D:/file.txt",
      "rollingInterval": "Day",
      "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss}] [{Level:u3}] {Message:l} {NewLine}"
    }
  },
  {
    "Name": "Logger",
    "Args": {
      "configureLogger": {
        "Filter": [
          {
            "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
            "Args": {
              "expression": "(@Level = 'Error' or @Level = 'Fatal')"
            }
          }
        ],
        "WriteTo": [
          {
            "Name": "MSSqlServer",
            "Args": {
              "connectionString": "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;User Id=sa;Password=*****; Initial Catalog=LogsDb",
              "tableName": "NmsRecipesLogs_Errors",
              "autoCreateSqlTable": true,
              "batchPostingLimit": 1,
              "columnOptionsSection": {
                "removeStandardColumns": [ "MessageTemplate", "Properties" ]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "Name": "Logger",
    "Args": {
      "configureLogger": {
        "Filter": [
          {
            "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
            "Args": {
              "expression": "(@Level = 'Information' or @Level = 'Warning')"
            }
          }
        ],
        "WriteTo": [
          {
            "Name": "MSSqlServer",
            "Args": {
              "connectionString": "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;User Id=sa;Password=****;Initial Catalog=LogsDb",
              "tableName": "NmsRecipesLogs_Info",
              "autoCreateSqlTable": true,
              "batchPostingLimit": 1,
              "columnOptionsSection": {
                "removeStandardColumns": [ "MessageTemplate", "Properties" ]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I know that `MSSQLServer` sink does not write logs to the database immediately, so I set `batchPostingLimit` to 1, but with no effect.

The question is how to ensure that this configuration is properly consumed by application and doesn't have any mistakes?

Comment: Do you include `"Using":  ["Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer"]` under the root-level `Serilog` configuration element?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning yes

Comment: Please clarify: are you asking how to verify *any* Serilog configuration? Or are you asking how to correct your specific configuration so that it starts logging properly?

Comment: @mason Well, it's both.

Comment: That's too broad. It's two questions. Keep your question limited to one.

Answer (score 1):

Serilog has a SelfLog feature that allows you to output diagnostic information about the Serilog configuration. You can find out more information about this feature [here](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Debugging-and-Diagnostics).

`#tl;dr` you can output the diagnostic info like so...

`Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(msg => Debug.WriteLine(msg));`

Comment: This should be a comment, rather than an answer. It doesn't explain why this doesn't work. It explains how to find out why it's not working.

Comment: He's not asking why it doesn't work though, he's asking if there is a way to see if serilog is properly configured. `The question is how to ensure that this configuration is properly consumed by application and doesn't have any mistakes?`